# Same input into [math]::round returns different results

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm parsing a file in PowerShell. I have this section of code (with debug writes)

```
$max_file_size = 0
$max_file_size = $value
Write-Host $max_file_size # DEBUG
$max_file_size = Convert-to-Bytes $max_file_size
Write-Host $max_file_size # DEBUG
[string]$max_file_size = [math]::round($max_file_size, 0)
Write-Host $max_file_size # DEBUG
```

I'm seeing two different lines with the same data. The first pass returns this result:

```
8192.00000P
9223372036854775808.00000
9223372036854775808
```

The second pass returns this result:

```
8192.00000P
9223372036854775808.00000
9.22337203685478E+18
```

Wat?

```
Function Convert-to-Bytes
{
    #Pass in a value and convert to bytes.
    param ($value)

    If ($value -eq $Null)
    {
        $value = 0
    }

    #Convert case to upper.
    [string]$value = $value.ToString().ToUpper()

    #Strip off 'B' if in string.
    [string]$value = $value.TrimEnd("B")

    [decimal]$output = 0

    If ($value.Contains("K"))
    {
        $value = $value.TrimEnd("K")
        [decimal]$output = $value
        [decimal]$output = $output * 1KB
    }
    If ($value.Contains("M"))
    {
        $value = $value.TrimEnd("M")
        [decimal]$output = $value
        [decimal]$output = $output * 1MB
    }
    If ($value.Contains("G"))
    {
        $value = $value.TrimEnd("G")
        [decimal]$output = $value
        [decimal]$output = $output * 1GB
    }
    If ($value.Contains("T"))
    {
        $value = $value.TrimEnd("T")
        [decimal]$output = $value
        [decimal]$output = $output * 1TB
    }
    If ($value.Contains("P"))
    {
        $value = $value.TrimEnd("P")
        [decimal]$output = $value
        [decimal]$output = $output * 1PB
    }
    If ($value.Contains("yte"))
    {
        $value = $value.TrimEnd("yte")
        [decimal]$output = $value
        [decimal]$output = $output
    }
    Return $output
}
```

Comment: Is `$value` really `8192.00000P` and where did you get `Convert-to-Bytes` from? Are you using ISE? Can this behaviour be replicated in a new PS session?

Comment: I'm using ISE. `Convert-To-Bytes` is a separate function that I'll add to the question. The first value is exactly what I'm getting from my session and it's taken from the target file. The second value is the returned value from `Convert-to-bytes`

Comment: I will try to prove it but it must have something to do with `$max_file_size`'s type. Perhaps its a string the secondtime around.... will test. THATS IT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare typed variable, then PowerShell add `ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute` to it, so all subsequent assignment to that variable would be converted to this type.

```powershell
PS> $Var1=$null
PS> [string]$Var2=$null
PS> Get-Variable Var?|ft Name,Attributes -AutoSize

Name Attributes
---- ----------
Var1 {}
Var2 {System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute}


PS> $Var1=1
PS> $Var2=1
PS> $Var1.GetType().FullName
System.Int32
PS> $Var2.GetType().FullName
System.String
```

At the end of first pass you declare `max_file_size` typed as `string`:

```powershell
[string]$max_file_size = [math]::round($max_file_size, 0)
```

So on the second pass anything you assign to it got converted to `string`.

Answer (score 2):

I placed lines in each `Write-Host` step like the following to add some type information:

```powershell
$max_file_size.GetType().FullName
```

So that I would know the type each time. On the first pass

```powershell
0 : System.Int32
8192.00000P : System.String
9223372036854775808.00000 : System.Decimal
9223372036854775808 : System.String
```

On the second pass *in the same session*

```powershell
0 : System.String  
#^^^ String here makes sense since last it was cast to string in the previous run.
8192.00000P : System.String
9223372036854775808.00000 : System.String 
#^^^ Here is does not make sense since it should be a decimal returned from the function like before
9.22337203685478E+18 : System.String
```

Still working on it but `[math]::round($max_file_size, 0)` is given different data on the second pass, a String instead of a decimal. Working on exactly why. You can see the difference this way as well

```
PS C:\users\Cameron\Downloads> [math]::round("9223372036854775808.00000", 0)
9.22337203685478E+18

PS C:\users\Cameron\Downloads> [math]::round([decimal]"9223372036854775808.00000", 0)
9223372036854775808
```

**Workaround**

I know that adding this line to the beginning of the code addresses the issue. This way it executes the same every time.

```
Remove-Variable max_file_size
```

Could also force a decimal to be returned from the function.

```
[decimal]$max_file_size = Convert-to-Bytes $max_file_size
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's super interesting that having the variable be a pre-defined string rather than null affects the representation.

Comment: I might be wrong on the assumption. Something about the assignment from the function is related. There is a PowerShell answer... just not sure if I can find it on my own.

Comment: I ended up changing `Convert-to-Bytes` to return a decimal. I'm still interested in what causes this behavior.

Comment: Co-worker thinks that .net is memoizing the (function, input) tuple and returning the computed value which was cast to a string. Not sure how to prove that yet.

Comment: Kind of though someone with more experience like Keith Hill would have been all over this

Comment: Not all problems are worthy of giants apparently. =P

Comment: You can use `decimal` literal `9223372036854775808.00000d` instead of `[decimal]"9223372036854775808.00000"`.

Answer (score 1):

**Forward**

This is more question than answers but if no one else comes to help maybe I can figure this out as best I can.

**Meat and Potatoes**

Just want to keep this answer separate for now since this might just be a workspace for this issue unless someone else has the answer without thinking about it. So I am trying to use `Trace-Command` to see if I can figure out what is going on. There is *a lot* of information to potentially parse through but to keep it simple to start I did this.

Created a ps1 script with your function and the following code placed twice

```
Trace-Command -name TypeConversion -Expression {
$value = "8192.00000P"
$max_file_size = 0
$max_file_size = $value
$max_file_size = Convert-to-Bytes $max_file_size
[string]$max_file_size = [math]::round($max_file_size, 0)
} -PSHost
```

Put in a line so I would know where the first pass finished and the second on started. Thought to start with `TypeConversion` as that seemed on par with the issue. I have the following findings (I will show differences only.) Note that all the code lines were prefixed with `DEBUG: TypeConversion Information` but it was removed here for brevity and readabilty

The first pass has some information in regards to the Math assembly which only occurs once which makes sense

```
: 0 :         Conversion to System.Type
: 0 :             Found "System.Math" in the loaded assemblies.
```

The shortly after that where the code for `$max_file_size = 0` and `$max_file_size = $value` occurs I see this in only the *second* pass

```
: 0 : Converting "0" to "System.String".
: 0 :     Converting numeric to string.
: 0 : Converting "8192.00000P" to "System.String".
: 0 :     Result type is assignable from value to convert's type
```

The towards the end where the real question come is what looks like the return from the function and the associated string assignment `[string]$max_file_size = [math]::round($max_file_size, 0)`.

1.st Pass

```
: 0 : Converting "9223372036854775808.00000" to "System.Decimal".
: 0 :     Result type is assignable from value to convert's type
: 0 : Converting "9223372036854775808" to "System.String".
: 0 :     Converting numeric to string.
```

2.nd Pass

```
: 0 : Converting "9223372036854775808.00000" to "System.Decimal".
: 0 :     Result type is assignable from value to convert's type
: 0 : Converting "9223372036854775808.00000" to "System.String".
: 0 :     Converting numeric to string.
: 0 : Converting to double or single.
: 0 : Converting "9.22337203685478E+18" to "System.String".
: 0 :     Converting numeric to string.
```

Look like the data leaves your custom function the same as "9223372036854775808.00000" but the assignment back to `$max_file_size` in the second pass is converting the value to a double as you can replicate with this code.

```
[double]"9223372036854775808.00000"
9.22337203685478E+18
```

I don't mean to waste anyones time with this but this is the best place for this issues scratch space.

Feel like `Trace-Command` might not get the information I need possibly because it cannot get debug information from the method `round`

**Plot thickens**

If I change the return variable to something like `$another_max_file_size` and then check the type of both `$another_max_file_size` and `$max_file_size` after the respective  multiple passes I see that `$max_file_size` converts to `[System.String]` like we already determined and that  `$another_max_file_size` stays as a `[System.Decimal]`

So we know now the source of the issue is assigning the output of your function from this line. Again, don't think the the return but the assignment operation itself.

```
$max_file_size = Convert-to-Bytes $max_file_size
#              ^ something is happening here.
```