# Showing error while adding element in List[int] in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powermock

```
$sumList= New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[int]
$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$preSumList= New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[int]
$threadInitDelay = [int]$commaSplit[++$eventIndex].Split(':')[1].Trim()  
$preProcessTime = [int]$commaSplit[++$eventIndex].Split(':')[1].Trim()+[int]$commaSplit[++$eventIndex].Split(':')[1].Trim()+$commaSplit[[int]++$eventIndex].Split(':')[1].Trim()
$respTime = [int]$commaSplit[++$eventIndex].Split(':')[1].Trim();
$index =$eventList.FindIndex({param([string]$s) return $s -like 'hi'})

if($index -eq -1){
    $eventList.Add($eventName)
    $sumList.Add($threadInitDelay)
    $respSumList.Add($respTime)
```

Getting this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Int32[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Add'.
At D:\Powercel\PowershellPractice.ps1:151 char:19
+                         $sumList.Add <<<< ($threadInitDelay)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound


Method invocation failed because [System.Int32[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Add'.
At D:\Powercel\PowershellPractice.ps1:152 char:23
+                         $respSumList.Add <<<< ($respTime)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.Int32[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Add'.
At D:\Powercel\PowershellPractice.ps1:153 char:23
+                         $respMaxTime.Add <<<< ($respTime)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.Int32[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Add'.
At D:\Powercel\PowershellPractice.ps1:155 char:19
+                         $minTime.Add <<<< ($threadInitDelay)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Could you please help me out?

Comment: What is the type of those variables? I mean check it with `$sumList.GetType().FullName`. I can see your code but if you have an open sessions where these variables were cast differently they wont work.  Restart your sessions or open new console and test again to be sure. Mathis, in another question, suggested you use `remove-variable`. `$sumList= New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[int];$sumList.Add(5)` worked for me. The type in your error looks wrong.

Comment: This could be a dupe target. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830659/same-input-into-mathround-returns-different-results/27873156#27873156. If I am right about the cast issue the answer there explains the problem.

Comment: Thanks man..got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible scenario is that you were testing and actually casted those variables like the error states. The error is not wrong. Those variables are not the list types that you have in your code. I can *almost* reproduce this issue:

```
PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> [int[]]$sumlist = 5,5

PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> $sumlist.GetType().Fullname
System.Int32[]

PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> $sumlist.Add(5)
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At line:1 char:1
+ $sumlist.Add(5)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException

PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> $sumlist = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[int]
```

While I didn't get the same error as you the point is the type of the variable didn't change even though I tried to recasted it. That is because of property of the variable [explained in this answer by PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875884/3829407). Have a look at the command `Get-Variable sumlist | ft Name,Attributes` and you *should* see `System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute`. Removing the variable and starting again I get your expected behavior.

```
PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> Remove-Variable sumlist

PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> $sumlist = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[int]

PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> $sumlist.Add(5)

PS M:\Scripts\Inno\Output> $sumlist.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```